# TypeError in Python Program

Tags: python, json, typeerror

Hello so I am writing a program that will prompt for a location, contact a web service and retrieve JSON for the web service and parse that data, and retrieve the first place_id from the JSON.

I am trying to find the place_id for: Shanghai Jiao Tong University

I have my code written, but I just can't get it to work. It has to be a small error because when I run it, I get a message that says

```
place_id = process_json['results'][0]['place_id']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is my code

```
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
    import json

    serviceurl = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson??'

    while True:
        location = input('Enter location: ')
        if len(location) < 1: break
        url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode(
            {'address': location})
        print ('Retrieving', url)
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        read_data = data.read().decode()
        print ('Retrieved',len(read_data),'characters') 
        try:
            process_json = json.loads(read_data)
        except:
            process_json = None

        place_id = process_json['results'][0]['place_id']
        print ('Place id:', place_id)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `process_json` is a list, or `process_json['results'][0]` is a list, and you are treating it as a dictionary

Comment: @chrisz Yes it is a list. So what would I have to do not to treat it as a dictionary? Sorry for the simple question... I am new at python

Comment: You cannot access a list like this: `L['string_here']`, you have to access a list by using integer indicies, like this: `L[0]`, `L[1]`, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're treating a list like a dictionary. A list is, as the name implies, a list of items with an incrementing index, `0, 1, 2..`. A dictionary is a lot like a list, except its index is named.

The reason your code isn't working is because, the JSON returned from the URL is a list. It looks like this:

```
[
    "AGH University of Science and Technology",
    "Academy of Fine Arts Warsaw Poland",
    "American University in Cairo",
    "Arizona State University",
    "Athens Information Technology",
    "BITS Pilani",
]
```

It seems you're trying to find the `place_id` of a university, however there is no `place_id` in the data you're searching in. But if there were, your approach was correct, however it did not account for the user not typing in the exact name of the university.